# Converting Image Converter python program to Exe not executing properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, executable

i am trying to convert my ImageConverter.py program to an Executable. I use

python3.6.7

pyinstaller --onefile ImageConverter.py

The Executable is made along with the folder **pycache** , build, and dist

The executable file is in the dist folder, when I try to run the exe the terminal pops up and performs the program and says complete. However no jpeg files are created or in the dist folder. I have also made sure my original .py file, along with my png files are also in the dist folder with the exe. is there something im missing here? are the converted jpeg files in another location?

The ImageConverter.py program uses PIL python package, it open the png files, converts them to RGB, than saves them as jpegs. The program works when running it as usual in terminal using python3 but does not work when trying the exe. any help is appreciated! thanks

ImageConverter.py. :

```
from PIL import Image #Python Image Library - Image Processing
import glob
import os
import sys

application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)

print(glob.glob("*.png"))

#Iterate through all the images
#Convert images to RGB
#Save Images

for files in glob.glob("*.png"):
    im = Image.open(files)
    rgb_im = im.convert("RGB")
    rgb_im.save(files.replace("png", "jpeg"), quality=95)


output_path = os.path.join(application_path, f'images')
```

Ive tried to run the executable multiple times. I put the png files and also .py into the dist folder where the exe exists and run. I was expecting the png files to convert to jpeg files, leaving png and jpegs in the dist folder after running exe. However terminal said :

PythonPractice/ImageProcessingPractice/dist/ImageConverter ; exit;
[]
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

There is no converted Jpegs in the dist folder

Answer (score 0):

[`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.executable) is the location of the Python interpreter you are running, e.g. `/usr/bin/python3` or `C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\python.exe`, not the location of the script you are running.

Therefore, for a system-installed Python binary, `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` will return something like `/usr/bin` or `C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts`, and `os.path.join(application_path, f'images')` will return something like `/usr/bin/images` or `C:\Program Files\Python\Scripts\images`.

But for a PyInstaller program that used `--onefile`, [that's likely a temporary directory somewhere](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works) that gets cleaned up right after the program is finished running.

It might make more sense to just use

```py
output_path = 'images'
```

without any prefix, which should be relative to the current working directory (wherever you are when you run the script).

Comment: ok I have checked the bin folder where my python3 lives and still no jpegs.... I made sure to check the correct bin by typing "which python3" and than doing a command+shift+g. paste the location of python3 and looking there but nothing... is there a way to have the executable save the files to the dist folder?

Comment: I tried to change my out_path to " ouput_path = 'images' " but am still not getting jpegs in the working folder

Comment: Right, `pyinstaller --onefile` binaries include a _copy_ of the Python interpreter that gets unpacked to a temporary location, then cleaned up. That temporary Python is the one that will be used. "but am still not getting jpegs in the working folder" do you get any error messages? Does this work if you run it from source (vs. the PyInstaller binary)? What value does `os.getcwd()` return?

Comment: I am not receiving any error messages at all only :     Infinites-MacBook-Pro:~ infinite$ /Users/infinite/Desktop/PythonPractice/ImageProcessingPractice/dist/ImageConverter ; exit;
[]
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

I added 
directory = os.getcwd() 
and received /users/infinite
I checked that location and no jpegs

Comment: Maybe you can help me with directing the converted jpegs to a set location like a folder i create on my desktop? would i even need an application_path?  When I run the .py from my directory that contains the png's it is good to go the program runs and the jpegs show up in that folder

Comment: Your code tries to print out the PNG it finds: `print(glob.glob("*.png"))`. Do you see that output? Are you entirely sure this is the code that you're running? And, again, does it work when you run the source with `python` (not via the compiled PyInstaller binary)?

Comment: Yes I am sure this is the code that I am running, and the code works when I run the script in terminal... running frok terminal I have the .py and pngs in the same folder... I change the directory of my terminal to that folder and run the script... jpgs are there

Comment: So you see the output of `print(glob.glob("*.png"))` print out? It includes the files you expect it to include?